# Using dynamicaly specified ng directives within my custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to create a custom table element like this:

```
<datatable items='tableItems' columns='columnsConfig' />
```

Here 'tableItems' is my array of items and 'columnsConfig' is configuration for column rendering, something like :

```
$scope.tableItems = [...]; 
$scope.columnsConfig = [
        {   
            name: 'check',
            with: '20px',
            renderer: function (rowItem, cellValue) {
                return '<input ng-click="clickHandler()" type="checkbox"/>';
            }
        },

        {name: "person.fullName", text: "Name", visible: true, width: '150px'},

        {
            name: "person.age",
            text: "Age",
            renderer: function(rowItem, cellValue) {
                return cellValue + ' years old';
            }
        }
 ];
```

Inside renderer function I can specify some additional data processing or templating.

In my directive template I have this:

```
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td ng-repeat="column in columns"
                    ng-show="column.visible"
                    ng-bind-html-unsafe="getCellValue(item, $index)">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

where inside 'getCellValue' function I invoking my renderer function. Here is directive code:

```
angular.module('components', [])
    .directive('datatable', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '../pages/component/datatable.html',

            scope: {
                items: "=",
                columns: "="               
            },

            controller: function ($scope, $element) {

                $scope.getCellValue = function (item, columnIndex) {
                    var column = $scope.columns[columnIndex];

                    // return render function result if it has been defined
                    if (column.renderer) {
                        return column.renderer(item, getItemValueByColumnName(item, column.name));
                    }

                    // return item value by column   
                    return getItemValueByColumnName(item, column.name);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

All works fine except ng-... directives. I think I have to do some additional processing of 'renderer' function results via $compile or something but yet I can't figure out how to achieve this. So the question is how make ng directives work when I specify them via my renderer function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations I have found next solution:

```
//after all DOM manipulations we should recompile parts that has been modified
setTimeout(function () {
    applyAfterRenderDOMChanges();
}, 0);

var applyAfterRenderDOMChanges = function () {
    var cells = $('td', element).children();
    $compile(cells)(scope);
    scope.$apply();
};
```

I have some concerns about efficiency of this solition but it works well so far.